# Set the basic authentication header

Tags: authentication

According http basic authentication scheme, it should be set a auth header when sign in a service. Suppose there is a simple name & password login page, how should I add a authenticate function to login button.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried the URLRequest and all the header related function, but there is bit less help to search out.